# Count maximum consecutive row out of total row for each day Ms-Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I Want total number of row for each and for each day want consecutive max row count where condition numb>2 and calibration!=1 from table in pic below

[image: The table structure]

and desire output should be

[image: The desired output]

Answer (score 2):

I think you want *conditional* aggregation:

```
select todaydate, count(*) as totalrow,
       sum(case when (numb > 2 and calibration <> 1) then 1 else 0 end) as [max]
from table t 
group by todaydate;
```

Comment: Be sure to accept this answer if it is correct, @priyankacharya